# get Twitter friends/followers' ids and nicknames

Tags: twitter

I am integrating Twitter into my mobile app. I am trying to get the friends or follower's ids and nicknames. One solution that I can find out is, using "friends/ids" to get the friends/followers ids, then "user/show" to get the user info.

However, "user/show" returns extended information of the user, if a user has a lot of friends/follower (say 1000), it will be very slow to get nick name of the user.

I wonder if there is any API that only returns ids and nicknames of friends or followers. Or there is other lightweight approach to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Twitter API call that just returns the screen names. You can use /friends/ids to get the user ids of 5,000 friends with each API call, and then use users/lookup to get the account info on 100 of these at a time. But you are limited to only 350 API calls per hour.

If you are building an app that is based on knowing *all* of the friends or followers of your users, you need to plan the way you present that. You cannot do what Twitter does, and expect to let someone login and then instantly display all their friends and followers. One way to deal with this is to ask for 24 hours to assemble their complete social network. The other technique is store every user's full profile into a database, so you don't have to look them up again.

Comment: On 1st request,I get 5000 followers. So, how can I manage to have next 5000 IDs on 2nd request..??

Comment: You're right for Twitter API 1.0, if I remember correctly, it was not possible to get directly Twitter following/followers screen_name. But with API 1.1, you can: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list